# Pod install not working in react-native mac os catalina 10.15

Tags: ios, react-native, installation, cocoapods, macos-catalina

> Error:
>   System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.3/usr/bin/ruby:
>   bad interpreter: No such file or directory

**in mac os catalina**

Comment: Maybe try using the cocoapods installed through homebrew. It works for me.

Comment: This is not specific to react native, but just the MacOS catalina 10.15 update breaks cocoa pods in this way

Answer (score 121, accepted):

You can fix it by running

```
sudo gem install -n /usr/local/bin cocoapods
```

Comment: Wow, the suddenly disappeared ruby interpreter in Catalina caught me off guard. Glad I found this easy solution.

Comment: This worked for me. But after running the command Need to set command line tools under locations in Xcode preferences.

Comment: @GurjinderSingh could you please expand what you mean by setting command tools in Xcode preferences?

Comment: @Solvitieg Go to XCode preferences->Locations Tab->Command Line Tools(If blank) Choose your current XCodeVer from dropdown.

Comment: Worked for me, you're a super hero

Comment: Selecting CLI tools not working also installing gems too

Comment: Finally, I found a solution. It all happens after the MAC OS Update.

Comment: The solutions suggesting sudo are less than ideal since sudo is a security risk

Answer (score 21):

I face the same problem on Catalina and tried these 2 steps hopefully it will work

```
brew install cocoapods --build-from-source

brew link --overwrite cocoapods
```

Comment: This solved the issue for me which appeared after migrating to MacOS 10.15.5 and xcode 11.5. Thanks!

Comment: This was the solution!

Comment: Works like a Charm

Comment: Had to first run  brew cleanup -d -v  then followed by the brew install cocoapods --build-from-source then brew link --overwrite cocoapods then it worked

Answer (score 8):

Run the following command in terminal

`sudo gem install cocoapods`

For more details follow this link.

[https://github.com/CocoaPods](https://github.com/CocoaPods/CocoaPods/issues/6778)

Answer (score 8):

This solution worked for me.

1) Go to Xcode preferences -> Locations 'tab'. [See image for Locations 'tab'.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TmVK2.png)

2) Check the Command Line Tools section. If it's blank, make sure your current command line tools is selected. [See image for Command Line Tools Section.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kzAhH.png)

3) Run `sudo gem install -n /usr/local/bin cocoapods`

It worked like a charm for me. Hope it does for someone else too. Happy coding!

Answer (score 1):

None of the suggestions worked for me. The issue could only be resolved by adding the correct Ruby path in the profile such as:

```
export PATH="/usr/local/opt/ruby/bin:/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/bin/:$PATH"
```

Answer (score 0):

I solved it like this

1) cd ~/.cocoapods

2) rm -r repos

3) sudo gem install cocoapods

4) pod install

Comment: unfortunately, did not work for me.  The `sudo gem install cocoapods` still shows the same ruby error.

Comment: First uninstall the all gem and pod tools and then try the above commands.

Answer (score 0):

> *Maybe try using the cocoapods installed through homebrew. It works for*
> *me. –  Snowfish*

This comment by `Snowfish` on the question helped me using cocoapods.